# Casper js - writing multiple test on same page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, integration-testing, casperjs

I have two casper test on the same page but the test above keeps interfering with the test below. (ie. if I put each test on its own page, it works. If its one the same page, the first test works and the second test does not.)

I was under the impression that there was no memory between start and run in casper test with anything that follows and that tests ran one after the other. Is this true and if so am I doing something syntactically wrong?

```
var routine = {
    login: function(email, pass, test) { 
        // casper.open(url); 
        casper.then(function() {
            this.withFrame(0, function() {
                this.waitUntilVisible('form#login-form', function() { 
                    this.fill('form#login-form', { 
                        email: email,
                        password: pass 
                    }, false); 
                });
            });
        });
        casper.then(function(){
            casper.withFrame(0, function() {
                this.click("#modalButtonLogin");
            });
        });
    }
};


casper.test.begin('Get login', 1, function(test) {

    var fs = require('fs')
    var data = fs.read('cookies.txt');
    phantom.cookies = JSON.parse(data);

    casper.start("https://web.test.com/#")

    .wait(1000, function(){
        routine.login('******@test.com', '********', test); 
    })

    .wait(1000, function(){
        this.withFrame(0, function() {
            test.assertExists('.wkKitTitle');
        });
    })

    .then(function(){
        phantom.clearCookies();
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});

casper.test.begin('Directs to correct url on form submition', 2, function(test) {

    casper.start("https://web.test.com/#")

    .then(function(){
        test.assertUrlMatch(this.getCurrentUrl(), 'https://web.test.com');
    })

    .then(function(test){
        routine.login('*****@test.com', '*****', test); 
    })

    .then(function(){
        test.assertUrlMatch(this.getCurrentUrl(), 'https://web.test.com/#kit/176637403872624641');
    })

    .then(function(){
        phantom.clearCookies();
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

EDIT:

For a diffrent example of what is happening the following works: (the only difference is order)

```
casper.test.begin('sign up components assertExists()', 7, function(test) {

    casper.start("http://web.dev.test.com/#/@page=signup.html")

    .then(function() {
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            test.assertExist('form#signup-form', 'Sign up form exists');
            test.assertExist('#modalButton', 'Sign Up button exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="first_name"]', 'First name field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="last_name"]', 'Last name field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="login"]', 'Email field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="password"]', 'Password field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="re_enter_password"]', 'Password field exists');
        });
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});

casper.test.begin('Get started model opens', 2, function(test) {

    casper.start("http://web.dev.test.com/#/@page=signup.html")

    .then(function(){
        this.withFrame(0, function() {
            this.waitUntilVisible('form#signup-form', function() { 
                this.fill('form#signup-form', { 
                    first_name: 'casper',
                    last_name: 'test',
                    login: 'testing@test.com',
                    password: 'pass',
                    re_enter_password: 'pass'
                }, false); 
            });
        });
    })

    .then(function(){
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            this.click("#modalButton");
        });
    })

    .wait(500, function() {
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            test.assertExist('#getStarted', 'modal opens');
        });
    })

    .then(function(){
        phantom.clearCookies();
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

but this does not:

```
casper.test.begin('Get started model opens', 2, function(test) {

    casper.start("http://web.dev.test.com/#/@page=signup.html")

    .then(function(){
        this.withFrame(0, function() {
            this.waitUntilVisible('form#signup-form', function() { 
                this.fill('form#signup-form', { 
                    first_name: 'casper',
                    last_name: 'test',
                    login: 'testing@test.com',
                    password: 'pass',
                    re_enter_password: 'pass'
                }, false); 
            });
        });
    })

    .then(function(){
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            this.click("#modalButton");
        });
    })

    .wait(500, function() {
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            test.assertExist('#getStarted', 'modal opens');
        });
    })

    .then(function(){
        phantom.clearCookies();
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});


casper.test.begin('sign up components assertExists()', 7, function(test) {

    casper.start("http://web.dev.test.com/#/@page=signup.html")

    .then(function() {
        casper.withFrame(0, function() {
            test.assertExist('form#signup-form', 'Sign up form exists');
            test.assertExist('#modalButton', 'Sign Up button exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="first_name"]', 'First name field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="last_name"]', 'Last name field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="login"]', 'Email field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="password"]', 'Password field exists');
            test.assertExist('[name="re_enter_password"]', 'Password field exists');
        });
    })

    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

Comment: Would it break your tests if `phantom.cookies` was shared? This is set outside the test contest, and so you'll probably need to clear it at the end of the first test.

Comment: good thought. I have edited the code here to use phantom.clearCookies();  but this and other tests not using cookies, still fail if on the same page. (they seem to not wait for a test to finish before running the next test.)

Comment: They use the same cookieJar, localStorage and cache. But since the cookies shouldn't be an issue and the others also, I see no reason this should be a problem. Where does the second test case go off the rails?

Comment: @ArtjomB. that is good to know I added an example at the end if you have time. Otherwise thanks for the input

Comment: Can you mark the assertion that fails in you original and the additional example?

Comment: @Artjom B. its always the entire second group of tests ( everything within the second casper.test.begin )

Comment: If you look at the CasperJS output, you should see exactly which assertion failed. I think it's also there when you would output as xml.